# Does pulse duration matter in laser induced air breakdown

Tags: laser, ionization-energy

(Before I start the question, this is not a duplicate of any question to my knowledge. Also yes I could maybe ask this on my other questions, but these questions aren't just for me they are for everyone looking into this so its going to be hard for them to find this question if it is posted in the comments of a totally different question.)

So I would state facts about if pulsation is required but I really feel like i have been told 2 different things so forgive me if I'm completely wrong. In the most basic single photon ionization the pulse rate of the laser simply does not matter as the required eV is exact to its nm so no matter what pulse the laser is still going to hit the nitrogen at 15.58 eV and maybe ionize. So when the process becomes a 2 photon process or a 6 photon process all I want to know is what are the requirements.

To better help me understand lets answer this question around nitrogen's 15.58 eV ionization rate. Like I said in previous questions I know that it requires an 80nm wave to complete this process, so what would be the new nm wave in a two photon process, what pulse rate is necessary for a 2 photon process, is mW necessary in this or does it once again only affect the brightness of the dot? if I'm missing any other key parts please comment as well.

Also if you guys don't want me posting these questions here (as I am not a physics person) I wrote a simple forum in php just for ionization http://www.ionizationforum.unaux.com

Comment: It really does matter to distinguish between quantities (photon energy, wavelength, power) and their units (eV, nm, mW). *Always* use the former unless you're giving explicit numerical values (so: "the required photon energy" instead of "the required eV"; but "nitrogen at 15.58 eV" is OK). You're in a physics forum and you're expected to learn and use the correct notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After building my own lasers now and learning a lot more, I am going to answer this question. I have built a ruby laser that has a lot of power, but a long pulse duration. It can put a hole in steel with a single pulse, but yet when focused, it can't ionize air. Power = energy / time. To say the least yes pulse duration matters... you need it to be fast (picosecond is suitable), so that even if the power you use isn't that great, you can still produce a peak power intensity of a lot of megawatts.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, pulse duration matters. More specifically, the photon flux would be what really matters in multi-photon excitation. Since shorter pulses tend to have higher peak intensities, pulse duration quite often matters.

A common way of understanding multi-photon absorption is by taking "virtual states" into account. A single photon can excite an atom/molecule to a virtual state, whose lifetime is limited according to the uncertainty principle. To have a multi-photon absorption event, another photon should hit the particle of interest while it is in the virtual state. This consideration will give you a set of requirements on laser intensity, etc, etc. Femtosecond lasers are often needed to drive multi-photon excitation.

Comment: can you further explain how a femtosecond laser helps improve multi-photon excitation? is it because the atom is constantly being bombarded by photons at a very fast rate?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer,  peak power (~ pulse energy / pulse duration) is what matters here. femtosecond lasers tend to have significantly higher peak power than nanasecond lasers, for example. Of course, higher the power is, more likely to have additional photons available within the cross-section of the atoms/molecules being excited while they are in "virtual" states.

Comment: A small correction - peak power matters, but the truly determining quantity is the peak intensity, i.e. the peak power divided by the focal-spot area. No matter how powerful your laser, if your focusing conditions are too loose, you won't see any multiphoton processes.