# What is electrical efficiency of ionized air

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, laser, ionization-energy

I have tried finding the correct answer to this question with no avail. I want to know what the loss would be when a path in the air is ionized and electricity is transferred from a source(lets say for example cloud!) to a source that can accept it(creating a potential gradient). but how much of the electricity would be lost through resistance of this ionized air. lets assume the ionization is done as best as possible and air is at atmospheric pressure. another example would be infrared lasers that have been proven to be able to ionize air " With the advent of intense ultrashort-pulse, near-infrared lasers, it has become possible to ionize atoms and/or molecules of a gas in a few laser cycles (a few femtoseconds—a time duration faster than inverse of the electron plasma frequency) and to generate anisotropic and/or nonthermal electron velocity distribution (EVD) functions by a process known as optical field–induced or tunnel ionization (OFI) (source:https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.aax4545)"
so I am thinking If I had a source of very high voltage energy on one side and a sharp metalic object on the other side and I shot 1 pulse of laser with the appropriate width to create a path from my source of power to the receiving source, how much of the elctricity would be wasted while moving through this ionized path?

This is the closest formula I found to define the ionization probability in semi classical appromximation is:
[image: Classical Approximation of ionization probability]

Comment: I don't see how you could hope to calculate this without knowing more information, such as the path length through the air, the beam intensity, the beam wavelength, and the beam diameter.

Comment: Related questions:  [Would it be possible to conduct electricity using laser-ionized air?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/453570/would-it-be-possible-to-conduct-electricity-using-laser-ionized-air)  [Does pulse duration matter in laser induced air breakdown?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/366247/does-pulse-duration-matter-in-laser-induced-air-breakdown)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert very interesting, sorry I am just trying to learn more about this very interesting self focusing and filamentation phenomena. why would the distance matter? is the air not ionized uniformly by the laser pulse? I am assuming as it ionizes the gasses it loses power but can we estimate an average? Electricity also has a loss in copper wire and we can give a measurement by unit distance or unit volume, why can't we have an estimated response for air per unit distance?

Comment: If you're talking about resistive power losses for a given voltage difference, the resistance of the ionized path will be inversely proportional to the resistance ($P = V^2/R$) and the resistance of the path will depend on the length of the path ($R \propto \ell$.)  Combined, this means that the power dissipated will be *inversely* proportional to the length;  a longer path will result in *less* power dissipation, not more.  So the "response per unit distance" isn't useful because power lost per unit of length isn't constant. ...

Comment: And all of this is assuming that the simple DC laws I'm using (Ohm's law, resistivity, etc.) are valid in a situation where the currents and voltages are possibly changing *very* rapidly.  In the end, what you're asking about is an interesting but very very messy problem and I doubt there's going to be a simple answer to it.

Comment: ok thank you. So lets assume a path of 1 meter but in order to know the width of the path, I would need to know the conductivity of ionized air given lets say I wanted to move something like an average lightning(300 million volts with 30,000 amps). I am trying to figure out what path width I would need to move lets say that much electricity for 1 meter(just as proof of concept). Also I think even the path is not wide enough once there is a connection between a source with that much electricity and a potential place for it to go it would force its way through air.